# OpenGL can not delete buffer

Tags: opengl

I draw objects with using `glBufferData`. I want to replace drawing data consecutively. And I want to delete bufferdata and I rewrite new buffer data but I can not do it. Because memory can not being released. And After a few times, I am taking System Out of Memory errors. How can I delete data? `GLDeleteBuffer` is not running.
My codes are given as below.

```
public void ReDraw()
        {
            for (int xx = 0; xx < 500; xx++)
            {

                this.DeleteBuffers(0)

                this.LoadDrawDatas(0, Obje);

                this.openGLControl.Invalidate();
            }

           

        }

private void DeleteBuffers(int data)
        {
            
            if (this.texturesBuffer[data] != null)
            {
                GL.DeleteBuffers(this.texturesBuffer[data].Length, this.texturesBuffer[data]);
                GL.DeleteTextures(1, this.textures[data]);
            }
            if (this.vertex!= null)
            {
                GL.DeleteBuffers(this.vertex[data].Length, this.vertex[data]);
                GL.DeleteVertexArrays(this.vertex[data].Length, this.vertex[data);
                GL.DeleteFramebuffers(this.vertex[data].Length, this.vertex[data]);
                GL.DeleteRenderbuffers(this.vertex[data].Length, this.vertex[data]);
            }
            if (this.normal != null)
            {
                GL.DeleteBuffers(this.normal[data].Length, this.normal[data]);
                GL.DeleteFramebuffers(this.normal[data].Length, this.normal[data]);
                GL.DeleteRenderbuffers(this.normal[data].Length, this.normal[data]);
                GL.DeleteVertexArrays(this.normal[data].Length, this.normal[data]);

              
            }

           
        }

private void LoadDrawDatas(int data,UcBoyutluNesneBilgisi obje)
        {
           Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, obje.Texture.Width, obje.Texture.Height);

            GL.GenTextures(1, this.textures[data]);

            GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, this.textures[data][0]);

            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData21 = obje.Texture.LockBits(r1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, obje.Texture.Width, obje.Texture.Height, 0, PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bitmapData21.Scan0);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
            obje.Texture.UnlockBits(bitmapData21);

            GL.GenBuffers(1, this.texturesBuffer[data]);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.PixelPackBuffer, this.texturesBuffer[data][0]);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.PixelPackBuffer, (IntPtr)(obje.texturesCoord.Count * sizeof(float)), obje.texturesCoord.ToArray(), BufferUsageHint.StreamDraw);




            GL.GenBuffers(1, this.normal[data]);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.PixelPackBuffer, this.normal[data][0]);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.PixelPackBuffer, (IntPtr)(obje.Normals.Count * sizeof(float)), obje.Normals.ToArray(), BufferUsageHint.StreamDraw);

            GL.GenBuffers(1, this.vertex[data]);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.PixelPackBuffer, this.vertex[data][0]);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.PixelPackBuffer, (IntPtr)(obje.VertexKoordinatlari.Count * sizeof(float)), IntPtr.Zero, BufferUsageHint.StreamDraw);

            GL.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.PixelPackBuffer, IntPtr.Zero, (obje.Vertexs.Count * sizeof(float)), obje.VertexsToArray());

            GL.GenBuffers(1, this.indeks[data]);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.PixelPackBuffer, this.indeks[data][0]);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.PixelPackBuffer, (IntPtr)this.indexsData[data].Length * sizeof(int)), this.indexsData[data], BufferUsageHint.StreamDraw);

        }

private void openGLControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
          
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
            GL.LoadIdentity();

            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
            GL.LoadIdentity();

            GL.Rotate(X, 1, 0, 0);
            GL.Rotate(Y, 0, 1, 0);
            GL.Rotate(Z, 0, 0, 1);

            GL.Scale(this.zoom* 0.01f, this.zoom * 0.01f, this.zoom * 0.01f);

         
            GL.PushMatrix();

            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.NormalArray);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, normals[0]);
            GL.NormalPointer(NormalPointerType.Float, 0, 0);

            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertex[0]);
            GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (texturesBuffer!= null)
            {
                GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);
                GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, texturesBuffer[0]);
                GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            }

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer,  indeks[0]);

            GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indexsData.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);

            GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.NormalArray);
            GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
            GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);

            GL.PopMatrix();
        }
```

Comment: Excuse me I wrote wrong I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `glGenBuffers` everytime you want to upload data to your VBO (the buffers created by `glGenBuffers` are called VBOs).

Once your VBOs are created, you can simply overwrite the data using `glBufferData`. OpenGL will reallocate the memory on the GPU by itself in the background.

Also, for better performance, if your VBOs are the same size from one frame to another, you can use `glBufferSubData` to update the content of your buffers without suffering the performance penalty of OpenGL reallocating the memory on the GPU

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem.